# Questions about pointers and C arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If you declare a pointer and a C `char` array such that:

```
char arr[100];
char *ptr;
```

Am I correct in saying that

`*ptr` is the same as `ptr[]` in other words it's a pointer to the first element in a dynamic array?

Then if I were to loop through a `NULL` terminated `char` array such that

```
printf("Enter a string");
gets(arr);
char *ptr = someCharString;
int increment;
while(*ptr++ != '\0')
     increment++;
```

So increment now gives the length of the string(assuming it's `NULL` terminated). I assume this is how `strlen` works..

So is this the same as saying `ptr[length_of_char_string]`

How do I reset `*ptr` back to `ptr[0]` so that I can loop through `*ptr` now that I have the length such as,

```
for(int i = 0;i < increment;i++){
   if(*ptr++ = 'a'){//Need ptr to start at the first element again
   //Do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: you can save the adress of the first element in other variable.

Comment: i reckon instead of `char *ptr = someCharString;` you meant `char *ptr = arr;`

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. `gets()` usage is a guaranteed buffer overflow vulnerability. Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in saying that
>   `*ptr` is the same as `ptr[]` in other words it's a pointer to the first element in a dynamic array?

No. [*Arrays are not pointers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/2455888).
When you declare `char *ptr;` then it means that `ptr` is of type `pointer to char`. But when you declare it as `char ptr[n];` then it means that `ptr` is an array of `n` `char`s. Both of the above are equivalent only when they are declared as parameter of a function.

I strongly recommend you to read [c-faq: 6. Pointers and Arrays](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

char * is not equals name of array. you could use pointer as a array (e.g. ptr[0] is OK), but you can not use array as a pointer(e.g. array++ is NG).

You can define a clone for ptr.

```
char *ptr = someCharString;
char *ptr_bak = ptr;

for(int i = 0; i < increment; i++){
   if(*ptr++ = 'a'){//Need ptr to start at the first element again
       ptr = ptr_bak;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
char *temp_ptr;

temp_ptr = ptr;

for(int i = 0;i < increment;i++){
    if(*ptr++ = 'a'){
       ptr = temp_ptr
       //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Is this an acceptable solution for your program?